# O&O Defrag: How do you auto-shutdown after defragging a hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, automation, shutdown, defragment

I want to do defragmentation and then auto-shutdown the computer after the defragmentation has complete. In O&O Defrag, there's a feature where you're able to execute a certain job after defragmentation is complete. I'm not so sure on how to create and utilize the Jobs, but it could be used to do a computer auto-shutdown.

I'm looking for a way to do this, but it seems there aren't a lot of questions being asked about this feature (Auto-Shutdown after Defragging).

I know that the defragmentation program wants the user to check on the disk, and do some comparison, but I just want to skip that.

I am using Windows 8, running on x64 with O&O Defrag installed. I only have a hard drive.

1. If the Jobs can be used to execute batch files, would it wonderful to use "shutdown /s /t 00" command?
2. If Jobs aren't used to execute batch files, then what are they really for?
3. Any other ways I can use to get O&O Defrag to auto-shutdown the computer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of the application are you using exactly.  If you don't have SSD on the system ( thats a good thing considering fragmentation of files isn't a concern on a SSD ) then just remove that information from your question.

Comment: Sorry about the misleading SSD information. I just liked to state the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 0&0 Defrag Professional and above allows you to create and edit Jobs.  One of those ooptions is to automatically shutdown your computer when the schedule job is completed.

The following screenshot briefly explains it:

[image]

You can read the entire manual [here](http://www.oo-software.com/en/docs/usersguide/ood16.pdf)